# Unable to to return a list instead of a queryset in my filter class

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter

I am trying to return a list instead of a queryset in my filter class's queryset function and I am unable to do it. It is redirecting me to a url with ?e=1 when I try to use the filter link

```
class InstructorAttendanceFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # right admin sidebar sub heading just above the filter options.
    title = _('Attendance Date')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'skipped_dates'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('reverse', _('reverse')),
        )
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):

        qs = InstructorAttendance.objects.filter(instructor=request.user).exclude(instructor=request.user)
        sch = Schedule.objects.filter(instructor=request.user)
        range_date = []
        for s in sch:
            # Some nested logic
                    if q.lecture_date != day:
                        range_date.append((
                            ('id', '00'), 
                            ('instructor',request.user),
                            ('course_name', s), 
                            ('lecture_date', day),
                            ('loggedin_date', timezone.now)
                        ))
        none_qs = InstructorAttendance.objects.none()
        qslist = chain(qs, range_date)
        if self.value() == 'reverse':
            return qslist
        else:
            return queryset
```

Usage in InstructorAttendanceAdmin:

```
list_filter = ('instructor', 'lecture_date', InstructorAttendanceFilter)
```

Comment: You have a lot of objects called `queryset` there (a function, a parameter, return type)...

Comment: Yes, please ignore all the other logic. The logic is functional. What I am trying to do is pass range_date list instead of queryset and it is not working. It redirects me to a different url `?e=1` instead of results for `?skipped_dates=reverse` It is a SimpleListFilter I am trying to create and customize

Comment: try this `list(chain(qs, range_date))`

Comment: no it does not work. it is still redirecting to `?e=1` instead of `?skipped_dates=reverse` Is my model's object tuple structure right superficially for the above columns? Could that be the problem that the admin view is not accepting it?

Comment: what about `qslist = chain(list(qs), range_date)`?

Comment: no, not working. Can I not just do a `list(range_date)` where I can add my own arbitary values? would the return value be a list of a tuple or a map to mimic the queryset results needed by the admin list view?